# 3 Controllers exactly doing the same function. What is the best approach in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter, controller

I have 3 controllers doing exactly the same, calling the same models and views. But I have to create three different controllers purposely.

Is there any way of extending one controller into another? Or calling a controller function into another? Or should I create a library for it and use it in my controllers?

Please suggest me the best approach.

Comment: if they are exactly the same, then why have three of them? Have one and be good with it.

Comment: Agree. Are you sure that these shouldn't all be the same controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not that familiar with CodeIgniter, but you can try to create a base class controller that contains the functionality you need, and subclass this controller for the actual controllers:

```
// CI2+ in core dir, libraries dir for CI < 2
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        // Your functionality
    }
}

class ActualController extends MY_Controller 
{
}
```

Comment: This is what I was going to say as well, that way you can just pass the index around.

Comment: This is the correct method, however, not specific to Codeigniter. You'll need to rename the `BaseController` to `MY_Controller` and put it in your `core` folder (if using CI 2+) or in your `libraries` folder (if using < CI 2). You'll then extend `MY_Controller`.

Comment: I updated the code sample in my answer based on the comment of @swatkins